# Getting error while compiling using rapc

Tags: blackberry

I gave the following command to generate cod file
D:\j2me\j2meSoftware\For Blackberry\BlackBerry\bin>rapc import="C:\temp\net_rim_api.jar" jad="MCSMobileJ2ME.jad" codename=MCSMobileJ2ME -midlet D:\j2me\Product\workspace\MCSMobileJ2ME.mtj.tmp\emulation\MCSMobileJ2ME.jar

It gave following error.  I am using midlet.  My class MCSMobileJ2ME extends MIDLet.

What is the init member it is searching and why it is searching in rim.resources with my class name appended?

com.rim.resources.MCSMobileJ2MERIMResources: Error!: Class: com.mcs.mobile.midlet.MCSMobileJ2MEMidlet has no member:

Thanks,

Comment: Exact error is -->com.rim.resources.TCSMobileJ2MERIMResources: Error!: Class: com.tcs.mobile.midle
t.TCSMobileJ2MEMidlet has no member: <init>

Answer (score 1):

Launch preverify.exe on your jar file and specify the same net_rim_api.jar. It is to make sure that your jar file complies to RIM API SDK rules and has compatible bytecode inside.

And when preverify.exe completes his work successfully and without errors, run rapc.exe.

Comment: I did that still it did not solve.  Then I added init() method (dummy) into my midlet class and recompiled.  With the new jar i did not have this error.